# Ubuntu MAAS server image upload

Tags: maas, upload

I am running a MAAS server 14.04 and trying to upload and image to the repo I am getting the following in the maas.log

```
ct  5 14:50:54 maas.bootsources: [INFO] Updated boot sources cache.
Oct  5 14:50:55 maas.bootresources: [INFO] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Oct  5 14:50:59 maas.bootresources: [INFO] Importing images from source: http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/
Oct  5 14:51:16 maas.bootresources: [INFO] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Oct  5 14:51:16 maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Oct  5 14:51:16 maas.import-images: [WARNING] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any boot images available.
Oct  5 14:50:09 maas.rpc.clusters: [INFO] Cluster registered: Cluster master (4c54c895-26a3-4db7-89fe-acfea3487fd7)
Oct  5 14:51:28 maas.bootresources: [INFO] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Oct  5 14:51:29 maas.bootsources: [INFO] Updated boot sources cache.
Oct  5 14:51:32 maas.bootresources: [INFO] Importing images from source: http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/
Oct  5 14:51:52 maas.bootresources: [INFO] Finished importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Oct  5 14:51:53 maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Oct  5 14:51:53 maas.import-images: [WARNING] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any boot images available.
```

This image was uploaded before however something changed and the image no longer is there.

Comment: I am able to hit images url
ping maas.ubuntu.com
PING maas.ubuntu.com (91.189.90.236) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maas-ubuntu-com.yangmei.canonical.com (91.189.90.236): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=79.8 ms
64 bytes from maas-ubuntu-com.yangmei.canonical.com (91.189.90.236): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=79.6 ms
^C
--- maas.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the image source to "http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v2/releases/" in the maas settings.